# Angular checkbox update not running a full digest onclick to display template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I make checkbox run a full digest onclick, instead of onblur?

My problem is, the checkbox click only runs the local scope for the directive it is inside.  I also have other directives that need to update onclick, instead of onblur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using ng-click and $scope.$apply() but I was getting $rootScope digest errors.  After looking around a bit more I added $timeout around the $scope.$apply().  This fixed all my issues.

```
scope.ngclickApply = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        scope.$apply();
    },0,false)
}
```

and in the html

```
<label ng-click="ngClickApply()">
    <input type="checkbox">{{label}}
</label>
```